# Setting targetSdkVersion attribute causes JavascriptInterface to be ignored in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

Really weird issue. I have an application. This app opens a web page and allows user to fill form data and extract data when results page shown. Everything works fine until I add `android:targetSdkVersion="17"` to `uses-sdk` section. JavascriptInterface doesn't work if this line added in AndroidManifest.xml

Works with this->  `< uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />`

Doesn't work with this-> `< uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>`

Does anyone experienced same or similar issues like this? Is there any problem with not setting targetSdkVersion in Manifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone experienced same or similar issues like this?

Yes. It is even covered in [the documentation for `addJavascriptInterface()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29):

> For applications targeted to API level JELLY_BEAN_MR1 and above, only public methods that are annotated with JavascriptInterface can be accessed from JavaScript. For applications targeted to API level JELLY_BEAN or below, all public methods (including the inherited ones) can be accessed...

Simply set your build target (e.g., Project > Properties > Android in Eclipse) to API Level 17+, and add `@JavascriptInterface` to the methods you want Javascript code to be able to access.